# Typescript не подхватывается определение типа

Tags: typescript

Репозитарий с кодом:
https://github.com/Ulibka68/pk1

Для стороннего пакета на JS необходимо написать определение типа.
Решил потренироваться на примере пакета console-ui:
https://github.com/ember-cli/console-ui#readme

console-ui сделан полностью на js
К нему также есть файл - определение типов он находится в пакете npm @types/console-ui

Если поставить пакет @types/console-ui то строка
`const ui = new UI(...`
становится типизированной (в том смысле что WebStorm показывает подсказку по параметрам)

Для начала я скопировал определение типа создав файл
`types/console-ui/index.d.ts`
Содержимое которого полностью скопировал из пакета @types/console-ui

В tsconfig.json добавил:
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types","types"],

По непонятной причине определения типов не подхватились и тестовый файл
`src/cons.ts`
остается не типизированным

Поскажите пожалуйста что надо сделать чтобы UI получило тип из моего файла определения типов

Comment: Всё же не «Typescript не подхватывает», а «WebStorm не подхватывает»…
Посмотрите там https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205979284-Typescript-does-not-resolve-modules-through-tsconfig-json-s-baseUrl-

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы!
Удалил node_modules и увидел что webstorm подхватил описание типа

Answer (score 0):

В ветке v2 поместил работающую версию типизации:

https://github.com/Ulibka68/pk1/blob/v2/types/console-ui/index.d.ts

Какие внес изменения:
удалил `export = UI;`
Документация:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require
говорит что это старая(imho) версия CommonJS когда экспортируется одна переменная (UI)

В стандартном случае переменные module и exports обеспечивают экспорт модуля CommonJS - но в данном случае экспортировалась переменная UI

В рабочей версии в d.ts файле я записал:

```
declare module 'console-ui' {
   export class UI {}
}
```

После этого включилась проверка типизации параметров функций класса UI